# Website Quality Assurance Testing

Tags: html, xhtml, accessibility

I have recently downloaded an app I have been looking for, for quite some time.  It basically spiders a website and shows references to dead links, pages etc:
http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html.

I am finding this very useful for quality assurance of the websites we publish.

I was wondering if anyone uses a application that spiders a site like this, but also checks things such as missing ALT tags, accessbility issues and valid xHtml code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I have used the W3C validator before, and it is good for individual pages, it would be good to get a bit of software that 'spiders' a site, and produces a report.  It seems the HiSoftware does this, but it looks like an enterprice level bit of kit, not really what I would be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using the W3C validator is a good idea as well.

[link text](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want accessibility checking, the one that I know of is HiSoftware's [Cynthia Says](http://www.contentquality.com/). There are some drawbacks - it only checks 1 page at a time (at least, I don't know of a way to check an entire site) and you can only check 1 page on a given site each minute.

However, [HiSoftware](http://www.hisoftware.com/) does make commercially available tools for accessibility checking, with regards to 508 and Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. I've never used any of these tools, though.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is an automation QA plugin for Firefox.  It is easy to configure using a single HTML table to write rules.

Comment: I use selenium already - but thanks for the reply. Really
like selenium.

Answer (score 0):

For many things you are looking for I would check out https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ tool. There is a free version available as well if your website is not too deep.
For accessibility testing check out https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe-devtools-web-accessib/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd?hl=en-US Chrome Add-on.